# Spring Websocket Handler not publishing message to all clients

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a Spring Websocket server, very simple one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
        webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(new WebsocketHandler(), "/socket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(1024000);
        container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(1024000);
        return container;
    }

}
```

And

```
public class WebsocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(message.getPayload()+"\n");
        session.sendMessage(message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("New Binary Message Received");
        session.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

When I open the client which is just a simple HTML with SockJS library, the client can send receive messages from the server but if I open a new tab with the similar client it is not able to receive the messages posted by the other client.

Is this because of `session.sendMessage(message);`? What should be the configuration that when one client posts messages all other clients would be able to receive it?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to send the data to other clients, you need to track sessions. As you can see in the document at this [LINK](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/WebSocketHandler.html) the handler also has two functions for after connection is open and after the connection is closed. So how does this help you?
You can keep a synchronized collection like `CopyOnWriteList<T>` or use `Collections.Synchronized`, when a client connects (`afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session)`), add this client to this collection or when the client disconnects (    `afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus)` ), you can remove the session from your collection. when you want to send a message to every client, loop over this collection and use the session to send Objects. if you still find this confusing, I can provide a code sample.